# Neural network symbolic inputs and weights

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

If I create a neural network like, for example, so:

```
net = NetGraph[{LinearLayer[3], LinearLayer[5], LinearLayer[1]}, {1 -> 2 -> 3}, "Input" -> 2];
net = NetInitialize[net];
```

I can then evalute its output at a set of numeric inputs:

```
net[{1, 1}]
```

When I do this with symbolic inputs, however,

```
net[{x, y}]
```

I get an error:

> "NetGraph: Data supplied to Input was not a
>   length-2 vector of real numbers (or a list of these)."

Is it possible to view a symbolic representation of the outputs as a function of symbolic inputs (and potentially symbolic weights)?

Note: I know I could reimplement neural nets without using the convenience functions to achieve this. My question is, to avoid reinventing the wheel, can I use `NetGraph` / other neural net functions to do this?

Comment: I don't believe this is supported at the moment.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189040/symbolic-neural-networks-in-mathematica?rq=1